# what must do to sent money from bitcoin to my bank account

Tags: sell-bitcoins

Where can I find my e-wallet and to must I do to send money from bitcoin to my bank account. am trying to send money from bitcoin to my bank account

Comment: This depends on the country you are in.

Comment: South Africa tell me how to send money from bitcoin to bank account and where can I see my e-wallet

Comment: @Zonwabele you can use a local exchange like altcointrader.co.za or luno.com to exchange your bitcoin to South African bank account.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple answer:

You can not send bitcoins to your bank account.
...except is some special cases when your bank accepts bitcoins. I do not believe your bank do that.

#### Long answer:

You need to exchange the bitcoins for money, say EUR or USD or your local currency. Lots of bitcoin exchanges can do this, but you need to have trust in the exchange, because they can stole your bitcoins and never send you the money.

I use two exchanges, but I am not sure if it is OK to recommend them here.